# Azure Lease Blob API 403 Error

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to lease blob for deleting it but my lease blob API code does not work due to happening 403 error.

**Generate Signature Code (PHP)**

```
<?php
$account = "myaccount";
$container = "mycontainer";
$accessKey = "myaccesskey";
$blob = "myblob";
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T');
$headers = [
  'x-ms-date:${date}',
　'x-ms-lease-action:acquire',
  'x-ms-lease-duration:-1',
  'x-ms-lease-id:49383176-ad23-4f85-acbf-01edcd02d177',
  'x-ms-version:2017-04-17',
];
$stringToSign = [
  // VERB
  'PUT',
  // Content-Encoding
  '',
  // Content-Language
  '',
  // Content-Length
  '',
  // Content-MD5
  '',
  // Content-Type
  '',
  // Date
  '',
  // If-Modified-Since
  '',
  // If-Match
  '',
  // If-None-Match
  '',
  // If-Unmodified-Since
  '',
  // Range
  '',
];
$stringToSign = array_merge($stringToSign, $headers, ["/$account/$container/$filename"], ["comp:lease"]);
$stringToSign = implode("\n", $stringToSign);
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, base64_decode($accessKey), true));
echo $signature
?>
```

I added content-length header because 411 error occurred.

**Lease Blob API (curl command)**

```
STG_ACCOUNT="myaccount"
CONT_NAME="mycontainer"
BLOCK_NAME="myblob"
DATE=`date +"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT" --utc`
ACCESS_KEY="signature"
LEASE_ID="49383176-ad23-4f85-acbf-01edcd02d177"

curl -i -X PUT https://$STG_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/$CONT_NAME/$BLOCK_NAME?comp=lease  -H "Content-Length:0"  -H "Authorization: SharedKey $STG_ACCOUNT:$ACCESS_KEY" -H "x-ms-date:$DATE" -H "x-ms-lease-action:acquire" -H "x-ms-lease-duration:-1" -H "x-ms-lease-id:$LEASE_ID" -H "x-ms-version:2017-04-17"
```

**Error**

```
HTTP/2 403
content-length: 774
content-type: application/xml
server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 98f7dbe2-801e-0017-78f2-b5d325000000
date: Wed, 07 Mar 2018 09:02:11 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:98f7dbe2-801e-0017-78f2-b5d325000000
Time:2018-03-07T09:02:12.1896957Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'qaRQQPDc8T8lFCTq5W6ZkjrJoX6W+a419RMd8MWJsUg=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT











x-ms-date:Wed, 07 Mar 2018 09:02:11 GMT
x-ms-lease-action:acquire
x-ms-lease-duration:-1
x-ms-lease-id:49383176-ad23-4f85-acbf-01edcd02d177
x-ms-version:2017-04-17
/myaccount/mycontainer/myblob
comp:lease'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

I have already tried other blob service API such a get blob but it was succeed. So I suppose that these codes have a few mistakes. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with `Content-Length` request header. Please replace `0` for content length in your `$stringToSign` with an empty string.

From the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services):

> **Content-Length Header in Version 2015-02-21 and Later**
>
> When using version 2015-02-21 or later, if Content-Length is zero,
>   then set the Content-Length part of the StringToSign to an empty
>   string.

**UPDATE:**

Upon further inspection, your `$stringToSign` is missing `comp:lease`. Please try by changing the following line of code:

```
$stringToSign = array_merge($stringToSign, $headers, ["/$account/$container/$filename"]);
```

to

```
$stringToSign = array_merge($stringToSign, $headers, ["/$account/$container/$filename"], ["comp:lease"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I modified Content-Length value of `$stringToSign` to empty string but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I've updated my answer with one more issue I discovered. Hopefully that should solve the problem. If it doesn't then please edit your question and include the value of `$stringToSign` you compute and the latest error message which shows the string to sign computed by Azure Storage. I believe the error you're getting is because these values don't match.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes. But still it seems that the situation has not been changed. So I updated my codes and error responses.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the value of stringToSign computed by your code?

Comment: Another issue I discovered is that your headers are not sorted. So your headers should be in the following order: x-ms-date, x-ms-lease-action, x-ms-lease-duration, x-ms-lease-id and x-ms-version. Please make this change and try again.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that I should update my code from modified points? I modified them.

Comment: Oh, should the order match at both ? I didn't know.

Comment: Your headers array is still not sorted. Please edit your question and include the latest code you’re using. Also share the value of stringToSign you’re calculating.

Comment: I'm very sorry. The both date were different. I should not separate signature generation code and http request code. It worked by modifying both date. I appreciate your help.